# Vagrant port forwarding to PHP server / Permission denied error on php -s

Tags: php, vagrant, vagrantfile

I am on OsX Yosemite and had to do [the steps here](https://www.danpurdy.co.uk/web-development/osx-yosemite-port-forwarding-for-vagrant/) to enable port forwarding.

I got this at the end of **vagrant up**

```
==> default: Running triggers after up...
==> Fowarding Ports: 80 -> 8080, 443 -> 4443 & Enabling pf
```

The issue now is if I ssh into my vagrant box and run a php server at port **443** by doing

```
php -S localhost:443
```

It says

```
Failed to listen on localhost:443 (reason: Permission denied)
```

Further on my box (host), a

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

returns an **operation timeout**

How do I get the php server working on vagrant?

Comment: Shouldnt "443 -> 4443" be "4443 -> 443"? (Or otherwise, shouldn't PHP be started on 4443?). Also, I wonder if "Permission denied" is indeed a port forwarding issue.

Comment: I tried starting at 4443, which would mean I have to do a curl http://127.0.0.1:443/ on my host box right? This gave me an "Operation timed out"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `php -S` as root (for example after `sudo -s` on Ubuntu). Ports below 1024 are privileged and can be only opened by root.

The port inside your VM is :443. But you can use `php -s 0.0.0.0:4443` for example. Listing on 127.0.0.1:4443 would also not work because the port forwarding does not access the VM via localhost - there is an additional (virtual) network interface inside the VM instead.

Comment: So I changed my vagrant file to forward 4443 to 4443. I got an "Operation Timed out"when I tried to do a curl on my host box.

Comment: Hi, So on my VM I ran php -s 0.0.0.0:4443. Still unable to curl from host box. I tried to hit 2222 which I think Vagrant sets up automatically, I am able to curl that from my host box.

Comment: If you run `php -s 0.0.0.0:4443` you also have to set the port forwarding from 4443 -> 4443

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your vagrant box is Linux only root can listen on ports below 1024. Usually people use a server like Apache or nginx to listen to the port as root and then drop all other permissions and pass off processing to php. Alternatively you could use iptables to redirect traffic to port 443 to a higher port. (And start your server on the higher port number)

Comment: "Alternatively you could use iptables to redirect traffic to port 443 to a higher port" — The output from Vagrant in the question shows that he already is.

Comment: No, the output from vagrant says he's redirecting host port 4443 to guest port 443. I'm saying traffic on the guest itself. So traffic to guest port 443 then goes to guest port X

Comment: Hey, so I made the port 4443 in both the host and the guest. Then a php -S localhost:4443. On my host box curl http://127.0.0.1:4443/ gives a connection timeout

Comment: Not knowing much about php I suspect the issue now is the localhost. Try php -S 0.0.0.0:4443 or sub the guest's ip for the 0s if that doesn't work